# How to check if value exist only in one or other range else give error?

Tags: excel, if-statement, testing, logic

I am trying to create an error check and do conditional formatting if there is an error.

Logic test required to pass is that either range I7:J7 should contain any value or range K7:N7 should contain a value, if there is a value in both the range then give an error. If both the ranges are blank then no error.

I am currently using below formula to check above logic, but it does not give error when both the ranges have value.

```
=IF(XOR(COUNTIF(I7:J7,"*"),(COUNTIF(K7:N7,"*"))),"","ERROR")
```

Please advise how I can get desired error check.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you checking `H7`? Seems irrelevant based on the context you've provided.

Comment: I have updated the formula to remove H7, this is another check which I am doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or this:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(H7),"",IF(XOR(COUNTA(I7:J7)>0,COUNTA(K7:N7)>0),"","ERROR"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this is should work for you:

```
=IF((COUNTIF(I7:J7,"*")>0)+(COUNTIF(K7:N7,"*")>0)<2,"","error")
```

Comment: Nope this does not work for me. I still don't get an error when I have got value in I2 and a value in K2.

Comment: @rikinbhavsar I did end up updating the answer, may need to refresh the page to see the update.  Should work now.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
=IF(AND(COUNTA(I7:J7)>0,COUNTA(K7:N7)>0),"Error","")
```